# How do you change the sort order of the fields in the shipping address pop-up in Magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento, checkout

I want to change the order of the fields in the shipping address form during checkout, and I did it through a layout file, which worked for guest users going to checkout who need to immediately add a shipping address.
[Form shipping address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4itzu.png)
However, when a logged-in user goes to checkout and clicks the "New Address" button, the popup that appears to add a new address doesn't have the fields in the order I want. As you can see, the order of fields looks completely different from the previous image.
[Form popup shipping address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n21Ui.png)
How do I make the fields in both forms have the same order?

The attributes(fields) should be arranged in this order:
street,
number,
department,
region_id,
province_id,
type_document,
document

This is the "checkout_index_index" layout that I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-fieldsets</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- The following items override configuration of corresponding address attributes -->
                                                                    <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- Make region attribute invisible on frontend. Corresponding input element is created by region_id field -->
                                                                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="number" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">71</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="department" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">72</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">90</item>
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region</item>
                                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                            <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.region</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <!-- Value of region_id field is filtered by the value of county_id attribute -->
                                                                        <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                                            <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="province_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">91</item>
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendorpro_CustomerAddress/js/form/element/province</item>
                                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                            <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.region_id</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <!-- Value of province_id field is filtered by the value of region_id attribute -->
                                                                        <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.region_id]]></item>
                                                                            <item name="field" xsi:type="string">ref_region_id</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="type_document" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="document" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">101</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="district_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendorpro_CustomerAddress/js/form/element/district</item>
                                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                            <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.province_id</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <!-- Value of district_id field is filtered by the value of province_id attribute -->
                                                                        <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.province_id]]></item>
                                                                            <item name="field" xsi:type="string">ref_province_id</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```